# Access other aws user s3 buckets using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am making an Django web application that can list users s3 buckets and also let me access the other users files in s3 bucket.
Is there any way that I can access other users accounts like some temporary credentials using boto3?

Comment: How are the "other accounts" going to grant you access? Some options: Bucket policy, role, user. Have a think about that process before starting your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

boto3 has the [assume_role](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) method which returns temporary credentials for the role.

In order for this to work, the account you're accessing must have a role with policies allowing access to the S3 bucket, and the role itself must have a trust relationship with the account you're calling from.

Also the instance that's running your django application should have an instance role that allows [AssumeRole](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) permission.

Code would look something like

```
import boto3

sts = boto3.client('sts')
response = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='aws:arn:iam::OTHERACCOUNTID:role/role-that-allows-s3-access',
    RoleSessionName='my-random-session-name',
    DurationSeconds=900 # how many seconds these credentials will work
)

s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)

response = s3.list_objects(
    Bucket='bucket-in-other-account'
)
```

Comment: OTHERACCOUNTID you mean the IAM user id that the other user has created?

Comment: I was referring to another AWS account.  In the case of a bucket created for a particular IAM user, it would be the same steps, just use your own AWS account number, and make sure the role you're assuming has the privileges to access that users bucket

Comment: so whats the ['AccessKeyId'] ?? is it of other user?

Comment: It's `AccessKeyId` for the temporary credentials generated from the [assume_role](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) call

Comment: sts = boto3.client('sts') should I provide access_key in this line?