# How to use AWS CLI within AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli

I want to Copy data from an S3 bucket in one account and Region to another account and Region which is why I want to use AWS CLI to be triggered by an entry to the source s3 bucket and the lambda function can then use AWS CLI to run aws s3 sync

So I tried using the techniques given here: https://bezdelev.com/hacking/aws-cli-inside-lambda-layer-aws-s3-sync/

Basically

1. Install AWS CLI in a local virtual environment
2. Package AWS CLI and all its dependencies to a zip file
3. Create a Lambda Layer

However even after I add the layer I still see the error *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli'*

Comment: I've always used the AWS SDK for whichever language I am using.
The SDKs hit the same APIs as the CLI and should cover most use cases. Sorry if this is not helpful for your scenario, but figured I'd suggest it just in case.

Comment: I see you tagged python. The sdk for python is called boto3 and is installed automatically in the lambda environment

Comment: I read through the blog you posted. If you can't accomplish what you need with boto3, then maybe a screenshot of your lambda's directories as well as your layer configuration would be helpful to debug

Comment: Have you installed aws cli locally? what do you get with `aws --version`?

Comment: @BransonSmith I want to Copy data from an S3 bucket in one account and Region to another account and Region which is why I want to use AWS CLI to be triggered by an entry to the source s3 bucket and the lambda function can then use AWS CLI to run aws s3 sync. Is it even possible to do this using boto3? if it is could you show me some tutorial somewhere?

Comment: Be aware that you can [replicate content from a bucket in one account to a bucket in a different account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html).

Comment: @YashJain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228373/access-other-aws-user-s3-buckets-using-boto3